# Laravel, sudenly changed the session to other users?

Tags: laravel, session

Did you have any experience with this weird thing, I have logged in with "Foo" user When I refresh the page or click another menu page, the current logged user changing to "Bar" user suddenly.

I have change session_name/cookie_name at config/session.php to unique name, set "encrypt" to true,

The issue is similar to this https://github.com/crocodic-studio/crudbooster/issues/1073

Maybe there any other configuration that I have to set?

Thank You.

Comment: You might want to check for any usages of `cache` that should actually be `session`.  I've run into situations where a cached value got rewritten by a race condition, and messed up the data that users were seeing, making it seem as if their session had been replaced.

Comment: This is for server caching .. turn it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your server using web accelelator? Or litespeed? You need to disable cache.. 
Im using this 

CacheDisable public /
CacheDisable private /

Add it to my .htaccess
Hope it helps.
NB sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 5):

What kind of environment are you experiencing this on? Is this local or some kind of cloud hosting where load balancing could happen?

The issue could be that you have a load balancer in front of your backend. After you refresh, you get to another backend and create a new session. Check your session.php and try using the database driver (read https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#configuration)

Answer (score 0):

For me in similar case the problem was in `nginx cache`, after turning it off at the server problem was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, i faced the issue on the very first app of My laravel app. i have done some unusual condition in the login middleware with the remember cookie of user which is stored in local browser and that time i don't know why some users have cookie generate same which i later figure out and fixed the issue..

Well that time portal is not deployed live. so no harm was there.

Comment: pointing out you solved it without expanding on the solution is not helpful.